# c# Regex WWPN validation

Tags: c#, regex

Need to build regex to determine valid WWPN of the format:
10:00:00:00:c9:2e:e8:90

Here, each combination separated by colon can be alphanumeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```
([0-9a-f]{2}:){7}[0-9a-f]{2}
```

Comment: Was just about to write the same thing myself. I need speed typing classes :(

Comment: @musefan: +1 for not crying to much :-D

Comment: @SandipSubedi your absoluteley right, that is because of the ``{7}`` parameter. Change it to the number of columns you have and it will work.